# WPF Как увеличить окно программы, по нажатии кнопки?

Tags: c#, wpf

Пробовал через c# не помогло. Можно ли как то увеличить в разметке ?

```
 <Button Height="22" Width="23" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"                    
                   Margin="0 9 40 0" 
                   ToolTip="Развернуть"
                    Background="#CEE3FF"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Name="btnExpand"
                    Click="btnExpand_Click">

                <Image Style="{StaticResource Expand}">
                    
                    
                </Image>
            </Button>
```

Полный код разметки вот

```
<Window x:Class="Librarian.Windows.StartWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Librarian.Windows"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="450" Width="800"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowStyle="None"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown"
    AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" x:Name="windowMain">

<Border BorderBrush="#FF42C4EB" BorderThickness="2"
        CornerRadius="20,20,20,20" x:Name="borderMain">

    <Border.Background>

        <LinearGradientBrush>
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#E7EBF7" Offset="0.0"></GradientStop>
                    <GradientStop Color="#CEE3FF" Offset="0.5"></GradientStop>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

    </Border.Background>

    <Grid x:Name="gridMain">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="98"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="39"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">

            
            
            <Image Source="/Resources/logo/logo.png" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Height="30" Width="28"
                   Margin="10,10,0,0">

            </Image>

            <Image MouseLeftButtonDown="Exit_MouseLeftButtonDown" Name="Exit"                      
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"                    
                   Margin="0 10 10 0" 
                   Style="{StaticResource Cross}"
                   ToolTip="Закрыть">
            </Image>

            <Button Height="22" Width="23" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"                    
                   Margin="0 9 40 0" 
                   ToolTip="Развернуть"
                    Background="#CEE3FF"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Name="btnExpand"
                    Click="btnExpand_Click">

                <Image Style="{StaticResource Expand}">
                    
                    
                </Image>
            </Button>

            <Image Style="{StaticResource RollUp}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"                    
                   Margin="0 9 70 0" 
                   Name="rollUp"
                   MouseLeftButtonDown="rollUp_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                
                
            </Image>
            
            


        </Grid>

        <Grid Background="#B5CBEF" Grid.Row="1">




        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="2">

            <TextBlock Margin="12" Grid.Row="2">My Footer</TextBlock>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Border>
```

**И последний вопросик. Как свернуть программу в нормальные размеры, и как свернуть вообще ?**

Comment: ***private void btnExpand_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {        
            windowMain.Width = 2000;
            windowMain.Height = 2000;          
        }***


Вот увеличивает, но надо увеличивать под размер монитора. Как можно прописать ?

Comment: 1. **Привязки**, WPF не любит обращение к UI через код. 2. Зачем вам это? `ToolTip="Развернуть"` -> за это в WPF отвечает [WindowState](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.windowstate).

Comment: Ну про WindowState не знал, спасибо.

Comment: ToolTip="Развернуть" Ну эта всплывающая подсказка при наведении.  Если убрать, то не какой подсказки же не будет.

Comment: А я вам что-то про подсказку сказал? Я ее привел лишь как человеческое и грамотное объяснение вашему `Как увеличить окно программы, по нажатии кнопки?`, то есть это зовется "Развернуть окно". Вы лучше беспокойтесь о том, что не слушаете нас и опять делаете черти что, не уж то не хочется научиться сразу правильному проектированию WPF?

Comment: Я пытаюсь, но не всегда получается реализовывать у меня в wpf.

Некоторые вещи мне проще через код сделать.

Comment: Ну так спрашивайте, мы тут всегда готовы вам помогать. А на данный момент я у вас вообще не вижу "попыток", ведь основной инструмент WPF - привязки, где они? Где хоть одно `Binding` слово в вашем коде? Где `DataContext`? Как видите, вы их игнорируете, делая кучу костылей, увы...

Comment: Binding у меня есть, его я использую к привязке полей из базы.

Comment: Ну, в вашем коде как я и сказал, этого не вижу. Можете сами нажать Ctrl+F и написать `Binding`. Зато я вижу `Click="btnExpand_Click"` и всякие `x:Name="windowMain"`, которых впринципе быть не должно (только если используются в XAML).

Answer (score 1):

Если обращаться к View.xaml из View.cs ничего страшного нет, тем более для подобных задач и тут никакого смешивания с бизнес логикой приложения ведь для этого существует ViewModel.cs